# ng:repeat not loading data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my controller function to get data from server.

```
function carsController($http, $scope, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getCarData = getCarData;

    function getCarData(){
        $http.get('/api/getData').then(function (response) {
           console.log(response.data.message);
           vm.list = response.data.message;
         });          
   }
}
```

Here is the data returned.

```
{
    "message":[
        {
            "emp_id":1,
            "emp_name":"toyota",
            "city":"city1",
            "nic_no":4554
        },
        {
            "emp_id":2,
            "emp_name":"sunny",
            "city":"city2",
            "nic_no":57412
        },
        {
            "emp_id":3,
            "emp_name":"tata",
            "city":"city3",
            "nic_no":1234
        }
    ]
}
```

and html code to show data. I am using **carsController as cars**

```
<div class="row" data-ng-init="cars.getCarData()">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Pages</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng:repeat="vehicle in cars.list track by $index">
        <td>{{vehicle.emp_name}}</td>
        <td>{{vehicle.city}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

instead of showing data, UI show 100+ empty rows when page loaded.

What could be the issue?

**UPDATED**

If I manually set value as below, This works well.

```
vm.list = [
        {
            "emp_id":1,
            "emp_name":"toyota",
            "city":"city1",
            "nic_no":4554
        },
        {
            "emp_id":2,
            "emp_name":"sunny",
            "city":"city2",
            "nic_no":57412
        },
        {
            "emp_id":3,
            "emp_name":"tata",
            "city":"city3",
            "nic_no":1234
        }
    ];
```

Comment: as Thailand pointed out -> syntax is ng-repeat

Comment: `ng:repeat` also works fine. Very less known fact

Comment: `vehicle in cars.list` might be `vehicle in cars.vm.list`

Comment: how have you defined vm in your controller?

Comment: You'll have to show how you have defined your `ng-controller`. Are you using controllerAs?

Comment: @SubhraJyotiLahiri I doubt that. If the OP has done `var vm=this;` and `vm.list = message;` then in the UI, it should be `cars.list` if the alias is `cars`.

Comment: @cst1992 yeah. I am using `carsController as cars`. Please check the updated question.

Comment: `vm.list = response.data.message.message` try this

Comment: @ricky Issue is, the JSON he's posted; it isn't indicated whether it's the response or just the output of the console.log. But why 100 empty rows then?

Comment: @cst1992 the JSON I have posted is from the `console.log(response.data.message);` in my controller and It's actually more than 100 empty rows.

Comment: @Bishan: Instead of assigning `var vm = this` in your `carsController` do that assignment in  `getCarData()` just before the `$http.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is, as you can see in the console log you have posted, response.data.message is an object. Not an array. 
Try this instead

```
vm.list = response.data.message.message;
```

The following will bind the message array

Comment: Tried this before. Then I got column headers only. no rows.

Comment: okay here's a quick hack so you can see how the data is binded to the view, above the ng-repeat in the html put {{cars.list}} and see what it shows

Comment: It shows the same output I have added in my question.

Comment: try the output of {{cars.list.message}}

Comment: It's print nothing. Please check the updated part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

1. You are assigning `vm.list` to `response.data.message`, which, as NJ_93 points out, is an object. Use

   ```
   vm.list = response.data.message.message;
   ```
2. **You're not calling your getCarData() function from your controller**. So the data is never fetched.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the problem is not because of you have used two different objects. `vm.list` for receiving the data from `$http` and using cars.list for ng-repeat

store data to `$scope.vm.list`

and in the UI use `ng-repeat="cars in vm.list track by $index`"

Comment: He's using controllerAs. There you don't use $scope in your controller, it's already injected.